# How to construct Similarity function from file

Tags: java, matrix

I have a task on Data mining. I have two requirements:

1. I need to be able to read and display the file".

   - I've almost got this covered.
2. I need to construct similarity function and distance matrix.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadExample3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "dataset.txt";// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
      Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
      // double sum = 0;

      while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
        String data = inputStream.next();

        System.out.println(data);
      }
      inputStream.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

My equation is:

> function = sqrt((pow((x1-x2),2))+(pow((x1-x3),2))+...n)

then the distance matrix is a table-like result.

This is some of my dataset.

```
1000025,2,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1
1002945,2,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1
1015425,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1 
1016277,2,6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1 
1017023,2,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1 
1017122,4,8,10,10,8,7,10,9,7,1 
1018099,2,1,1,1,1,2,10,3,1,1 
1018561,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1 
1033078,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5 
1033078,2,4,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1 
1035283,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1 
1036172,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1
1041801,4,5,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,1
1043999,2,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1
1044572,4,8,7,5,10,7,9,5,5,4
1047630,4,7,4,6,4,6,1,4,3,1 
1048672,2,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1
```

where the first line is the id and for the calculation is the rest line

how to call number 2 in id=1000025 then add to number 2 in id=1002945. Do i need to declare it first or is the any other way to call directly from the file and insert into the calculation function?

then the calculation continue until the end of file. note that the numbers in id=1000025 is the constant as x1. Meanwhile x2 is the other id's number that need to be calculate.

Comment: And what the question is? It seems that your assignment is really clear; so why don't you ask your instructor what you are supposed to exactly provide?

Comment: And you want us to give you the code for it? What's the question?

Comment: not really. i want to learn how to call the data in the file and insert into the calculation function. sorry for not being clear. @Jägermeister

Comment: there is edit option under your post, use it to update your question, not the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have finished reading the data line by line.

Now in stead of just printing the `String`, you should parse it and separate the numbers.

- You can use `String#split` method to separate them using comma as the delimiter.
- The method will return an array of `String`s for each line.
- You can then use `Integer.parseInt` method to convert them to `int`
- Fill those integers in an array of integers.
- Insert the array to an `ArrayList` so you would not need to worry about size.

Now, after finishing reading the file, you can access all numbers as you wish and put them in your function.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.